# MULE SFTP Oubound retry is not working

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have use case as below.

A mule flow with file as inbound and sftp as outbound(crush ftp). I am trying to implement the retry mechanism when sftp server goes down. I have created retry policy on sftp connector but its not working. Then i used until successful scope on sftp outbound with retry configurations, this step also didn't worked.

But when i made my sftp as req-res , until successful scope retry mechanism is working.

Can some one guide me is there any connector level configuration (using spring beans) or any other configurations to make sftp retries for one-way MEP.!

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues here:

1. Retry policies are legacy terms and are now called Reconnection Strategies. "Retry policies" unfortunately suggest that messages will be retried -  which they won't - http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Reconnection+Strategies
2. Until-successful needs the nested message processor or endpoint to be synchronous so it can inspect the response to deem whether or not it was successful.

Comment: hi ryan , that for response. from 2 point i cant understand if outbound is one-way we cant achieve retry mechanism using until successful. Is there any alternative way to do retry on sftp outbound . really appreciate your help on this.